# Alternatives to Gazebo Fortress (Building Editor) Feature?

Tags: gazebo, ros2, simulation, simulator-gazebo, gazebo-simulator

I've recently transitioned to using **Gazebo Fortress** and noticed that it lacks a built-in **building editor feature**, which was a beneficial tool in Gazebo Classic. This editor was essential for creating custom environments for my robotics simulations.

For those who have been working with Ignition Fortress or have faced similar challenges:

1. What are the most recommended alternatives or tools you've used to design environments for Gazebo Ignition?
2. Are there any best practices or specific workflows you've adopted to bridge this gap?
   Has anyone found a workaround or method to integrate environments from other tools effectively into Ignition?

I'm particularly interested in solutions that are tried and tested in real-world projects, as this would provide insights into their robustness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the more general case, refer to [this previous question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/24926/how-do-people-create-complex-models-worlds-in-the-gazebo/24927#24927). This is not specifically aimed at modeling buildings though.

Re. buildings: there are plenty tutorials [e.g. for Blender](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+model+a+house+from+2d+floorplan&oq=blender+model+a+house+from+2d+floorplan) but I think this would still involve more work than using the building editor. However, you could install both Gazebo Classic and Gazebo Fortress, create the SDF using the building editor and then use that SDF in Fortress?

Alternative is to [buy a model online](https://www.google.com/search?q=PBR+low+poly+model+house) and use that. Though you will typically need to clean up the model and reapply the textures in Blender and then bake the textures and/or light map if you want realistic rendering. This is **a lot** of work, certainly if you have never done that yet and need to find out how everything works. But the result can be really nice. E.g. see the demo shown in the [release video](https://vimeo.com/868835608) of Gazebo Harmonic.